# Extract/Repack EEPROM Dump

Tags: firmware-analysis

I want to get more information from this dump I have:

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=42095249658483515063

```
binwalk dump.bin

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
56368         0xDC30          U-Boot version string, "U-Boot 1.1.4-2  (Jun 10 2016)"
56400         0xDC50          CRC32 polynomial table, big endian
65536         0x10000         uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x4FD6C064, created: 2016-10-12 09:53:26, image size: 3729430 bytes, Data Address: 0x80060000, Entry Point: 0x80064CE0, data CRC: 0x6B3A6FD3, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "runtime"
65600         0x10040         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 12767476 bytes
```

I already used `binwalk -Me dump.bin` and got `_10040.extracted/cpio-root/` with the main content. But it looks somehow incomplete.

After reading around in the files eg `init` I see, that there are multiple mtd "partitions" which would be nice to separate them from the dump. I hope that it will help me to understand the firmware and how update process works.

Also I found in the hexdump some PRIVATE information about the device like device_pass, device_wpapass and so on, which I replaced all with a 1. But it is also niceto  know where this information's are stored on the device to see how they are queried.

The problem for me is to separate all partitions/information from this dump. At least I want to see, if it is possible to disconnect the [device](https://github.com/openv/openv/wiki/Vitoconnect-100) from the cloud and only use it locally - but it looks like the firmware builds only a connection between the interface (connected to the heater) and the cloud server - so all logic is on the cloud.

Maybe it is possible to mod the firmware with a remote shell or make a MITM possible to investigate on runtime state.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cpio archive in the lzma compressed section

Layout of the dump.bin file:

```
00000000 - 00010000  bootloader, baseaddress = 0x9f000000
0000f120 - 0000f194 "bootargs=flash_part=1 uboot_version=1.1.4-2", "bootcmd=bootm 0x9F010000", "bootdelay=0", "baudrate=115200", "loadaddr=0x80800000"
0000f5c0 - 00010000   '0xff'
00010000 - 00010040  uImage header  ( the system partition )
00010040 - 0039e856   LZMA compressed data
0039e856 - 007f1000   '0xff'
007f1000 - 007f1440  The 'art' data partition
007f1440 - 007f9000   '0xff'
007f9000 - 007f9142   JSON: 
007f9142 - 00800000   '0xff'
```

### extract the lzma section:

```
dd bs=1 skip=$[0x00010040] count=$[0x38E816] if=dump.bin  | lzcat > dump-10040.bin
```

Layout of the lzma compressed data:

```
00000400 - 002D14CC   probably all linux kernel.
002D14CC - 00c2ced0   cpio archive
```

### list the files in the cpio archive

```
dd bs=1 skip=$[0x2D14CC] if=dump-10040.bin | cpio -ivt
```

I found 104 files and 183 symlinks in the cpio section.

The `vitoconnect-ol` binary handles the web interface.

The `init` scripts tells you everything it does when booting - not very much, basically: run the vitoconnect binary.

And, if you are wondering why there are not that many tools: `busybox` has all the standard unix commandline tools packaged in one binary.

From the string `AR9331 bootldr`,  i assume your device has a [ar9331](https://openwrt.org/docs/techref/hardware/soc/soc.qualcomm.ar71xx#ar9331)  chip, which has plenty of [documentation](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr703n/ar9331_pinout) available on openwrt, including the full datasheet.

### about flash partitions

```
/dev/mdt1    system1
/dev/mdt2    system2

/dev/mtd4    user config
/dev/mtd5    json config
```

/dev/mtd1 and /dev/mtd2  both contain the system, alternating between upgrades.

quote from openwrt:

> Requires a WiFi firmware called “ART” (Atheros Radio Test). It holds
>   device specific wireless calibration data, thus using a generic or the
>   wrong firmware causes FCC incompliance and poor wireless performance.
>   Usually the firmware is stored in an ART partition located at the last
>   64KiB of the flash. If the ART partition is missing or corrupt, ath9k
>   (wireless driver) won't come up anymore.

Comment: Hmm, this is not much more information I also got. I Requested more in detail to the different mtd sections and to which mtd the private informations gos to. Also I like to mod the image, so the question is how to repack after modification.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. But I still miss the information how I get the address of mtd1-5 and how to repack after modify/add files (eg the init script) And what command you used to get the layout of the bin you provided would also be nice.